# Wordpress and databases

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, cpanel

Please I need help ...
I have a website created by using wordpress and I want to add to pages one login for my students and one login for my colleagues. according to each login a private page should open and display my student report. and for my colleagues I want them to see the name of their students and to be able to assign grades to them.

so do I need to create a database in the c panel in mysql database and create tables in phpmyadmin?

I need a brief description please

Comment: I would be happy to give you the PHP code you would require for this, but it doesn't sound like that's what you are looking for? The easiest way forward would be to investigate membership plugins - they would allow you to restrict access to various pages based on the level of membership that a user has.

Comment: oh many thanks ... I am now designing it from scratch using PHP and mysql